Will it cause damage to unplug my fridge for 20 seconds?
My fridge is plugged into a multi-socket plug adaptor and I wanted to take it out of that and plug it in directly to the socket, which should only take 20 seconds or so. Would that be fine to do immediately? In other words, take the multi-adaptor out, then put the fridge plug in directly? I read stuff about leaving it off for a certain amount of time but wonder if it's just a matter of seconds if it would be ok. Plus the fridge will be stationary. It's just that I need the multi-plug adaptor for something else and I've never had anything else plugged into it.
Thanks a lot

Thanks a lot for the replies everyone. I am hesitating just leaving it as it is.
It's one of those half sized fridges (about waist height).  Once I was trying to get ice out of the fridge as it builds up a lot and I think I stupidly damaged the thermostat. Since then the temperature didn't seem to work very well at all and wasn't logical - on the coldest option it could leak water or the lowest option could freeze stuff on the top shelf. So, I just never touch that nowadays. In view of that maybe changing plugs could be the thing that kills it ;)

If you unplug the refrigerator while it is running and then plug it in again quickly, the refrigerator’s compressor may have trouble starting due to the pressure difference remaining in the refrigerant tubes from when it was just running.
(I once made this mistake, many years ago, trying to plug a fridge into a Kill-a-Watt power meter. It made a horrible noise and I unplugged it again. At the time I assumed it must be some kind of incompatibility, but now I know more about the physics of compressors and of power meters and it's obvious that this must have been the problem.)
Doing this once is unlikely to cause significant harm, because compressors are protected against this type of overload (after all, they have to be designed to survive power interruptions), but if you are going to be unplugging it on purpose, it is best to avoid the stress entirely by either unplugging it while it is not running (which will be best for maintaining temperature, anyway) or wait before plugging it back in to let the refrigerant pressure drop.
Wait how long? I don't know, but probably not very long. Maybe 20 seconds would be plenty. The important part is that there is no time that is short enough (that you can achieve by hand) that it's better than waiting. Don't feel like you should hurry.

And the easy way to get it to the not-running state is to note the thermostat setting and then adjust appropriately. Because it will always have just started a cooling cycle at the moment you want to unplug it.

You can disconnect and reconnect a fridge or freezer with no problems.
The issue is if you physically move it which can cause the gas to lodge in certain parts of the pipework and cause an "airlock" well gas lock which can damage the compressor.

Yeah, the issue isn't gas but oil -- if you put a fridge on its side, then the oil all drains out of the compressor (where the oil sump is) into the pipework, which means you need to wait to fire it up after you upright it again lest you fire up the compressor with no oil in it >.> not an issue if it stays upright though
